# JDBC query: wait until some result is returned

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I need to develop a JDBC application that will wait for a record that satisfies a certain condition and then return it for processing.
I can't use triggers as this is prohibited on the project.
So,  I'm looking for a way to submit an SQL query (may be a cursor?) so that it would not return an empty result immediately but wait for a certain period of time for the required data added to the table and then return back either the data or an empty result on timeout.
We're on PG 9.6

Thank you.